# iOS App with payment via browser

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment

I am developing an iOS Application for creating QRCodes. Also it allows the user to purchase some custom designs to customize the QRCode. We have already developed the app by loading the webview (our existing website) in the app and perform the purchase. But Apple has rejected the app as it is a digital good and asked to use IAP.

Here I have a small question:
Does Apple approve if we navigate the user to the browser window for processing the payment? Instead of using IAP?

**One more question:**

What if web has a credit point mechanism and let the user to navigate to the browser to buy the credits. Then come back to the app and purchase the items using those credit points. In this case, the payment is happening outside the app. Will this satisfy Apple guidelines?

Comment: They already didn't approve that approach...

Comment: Updated my answer, please check @Wain

Answer (score 0):

You can have external payment, but only if you also have IAP. And your external payment can't be any cheaper than the corresponding IAP.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand completely. Are you saying that, even if I use external payment, the app should have IAP option? Means, the app should have both the options and let the user to decide which one to choose?